# threading timer object not working as expected

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

I have a function (solve()) that will more often than not terminate within a few seconds. I want to make a timer that will automatically terminate the entire program if the function does not terminate within five seconds. I achieved this with a timer object in the following code:

```
clock = threading.Timer(5 , terminator())
clock.start()
solve(sudoku_board)
clock.cancel()
print(sudoku_board)
```

where the function terminator is:

```
def terminator():
    print("no solutions were found in time.\n")
    raise NoSolutionError()
```

and the error is:

```
class NoSolutionError(Exception):
    pass
```

For some reason, the error is raised every single time I run the code before the 5 second interval has elapsed. I'm not sure why this is, any insight?

Comment: The reason is simple:
`clock = threading.Timer(5 , terminator())` should be `clock = threading.Timer(5 , terminator)`.
You must pass a function to Timer but you pass terminator() which means you pass the returned value of terminator (and you are calling terminator immediately)

Comment: Silly me! Thanks, I never would've noticed.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome